# Error in verifying sbt installation

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to Scala and have just downloaded sbt on my Mac.

After installing using the following command -

```
brew install sbt
```

i am trying to verify that the installation completed successfully by running this command -

```
sbt --version
```

I am expecting something like -

```
sbt launcher version 0.13.0
```

but getting the following instead -

```
sbt --version
[error] Not a valid command: version (similar: session)
[error] version
[error]        ^
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall sbt on my machine but in vain.

Can someone let me know what I could be missing here?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

SBT launcher script simply doesn't support `--version`. Run `sbt -h` to see supported options. To show the SBT version used for current project, run `sbt "show sbtVersion"`.